# AWS AppMesh load balancing without ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-app-mesh

I'm currently testing AWS AppMesh with ECS and is wondering if there's a default load-balancing algorithm for distributing the requests among the running tasks.

For example I have:

- 1 instance of serviceA
- 2 instances of serviceB (serviceB1, serviceB2)
- serviceA calls serviceB

Upon testing, I noticed that all the requests are forwarded to serviceB1 only. serviceB2 is running, in fact I can access the service deployed to it.